# Eclipse cdt's "export project settings" does not export library settings

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to export the projects settings of a CDT project. I create the export navigating to FILE->export... and choosing c/c++ project settings.

When import this settings I find that include directories are correctly imported, but libraries are in blank. Both libraries and includes are workspace related paths...

Is it a bug or a feature? How could I export the library paths and libraries to add?